# Python: Write Nested JSON as multiple elements in List

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion

after two almost three days of programming, I am seeking for help.

What I want to do: Import Json string/ file and write it to a database. There are multiple combination of the input (cars). To lowest nested dict/ list defines the number of elements of a list which will be written in the DB.

Here is the JSON/ String:

```
input = [{"id":"BMW_1_Series",
        "years":[{"id":10052,"year":2008,
                    "styles":[{"id":560,"name":"128i 2",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conve"},"trim":"128i"},
                              {"id":561,"name":"135i ",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conver"},"trim":"135i"}
                              ]
                  },
                 {"id":427,"year":2016,
                  "styles":[{"id":433,"name":"228i ",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Conve", "niceName":"conver"},"trim":"228i SULEV"},
                            {"id":431,"name":"M235i",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Coupe", "niceName":"m235i"},"trim":"M235i"}
                            ]
                  }
                 ]
          }
         #I deleted the other entries, but it is a list
         ]
```

The output should be a dict and the keys for a subdict should be a prefix for the sub-key:

```
{'id': 427, 'year': 2016, 'styles_id': 431, 'styles_name': 'M235i',   'styles_trim': 'M235i', 'submodel_body': 'Coupe', 'submodel_niceName': 'm235i'}
```

I got it to work from years onwards:

```
for s in years:#styles
    outputA ={}
    for specifierA, valueA in s.items():
        if isinstance(valueA, list):
            for A in valueA:
                if isinstance(A, dict):
                    outputB = {}
                    for specifierB, valueB in A.items(): #submodel
                        if isinstance(valueB, dict):
                            for specifierBB, valueBB in valueB.items():
                                outputA[specifierB+"__"+specifierBB]= valueBB
                        else:
                            outputA[specifierA+"_"+specifierB]= valueB
                else:
                    outputA[specifierA] = valueA

        elif isinstance(valueA, dict):
            outputB = {}
            for specifierB, valueB in valueA.items(): #submodel
                outputA[specifierA+"_"+specifierB]= valueB
        else:
            outputA[specifierA] = valueA
    print(str(outputA))
    output.append(outputA)
```

I stoped here as I wanted to have a general case on how to read JSON files containing dicts, list and normal values.

My approach for that so far (it is not working and I spent three days on it... (I delted all the intermediate prints for easier reading) *Note: COde is a continuous loop...

```
def readL(input, prefix=""):
    x = True
    output={}
    k=0
    while (x):
        k+=1
        x=False
        if isinstance(input, list):
            print("LIST: "+str(input))
            for A in input:
                if isinstance(A, dict):
                    output = dict(output, **readL(A))
                elif isinstance(A, list):
                    output = dict(output, **readL(A))
        elif isinstance(input, dict):           
            for specifierB, valueB in input.items(): #submodel
                if isinstance(valueB, dict):
                    specifierB = str(specifierB)+"_"
                    output = dict(output, **readL(valueB,specifierB))
                if isinstance(valueB, list):
                    specifierB = str(specifierB)+"_"
                    output = dict(output, **readL(valueB,specifierB))  
                spec =  prefix+specifierB                
                output[spec] = valueB  

#check if Output Dict contains list or Dict -> continue loop
        for specifierT, valueT in output.items():
            if isinstance(valueT, dict) or isinstance(valueT, list):
                x = True
        if k ==1:# I have a continues loop so far, thats why
            break
    return(output)

readL(test)
```

Basically, I want to have a recursive function that continuesly calls itself until no dict/ list is in the output anymore.

I am also open to any other faster methods on how to read the input.

I am very desperately looking forward for some advice. Please bear with me, i am pretty new to Python.

THANKS A LOT!

**UPDATE**

I found a partial solution at [Flattening Generic JSON List of Dicts or Lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512957/flattening-generic-json-list-of-dicts-or-lists-in-python) from @poke

```
def splitObj (obj, prefix = None):
    '''
    Split the object, returning a 3-tuple with the flat object, optionally
    followed by the key for the subobjects and a list of those subobjects.
    '''
    # copy the object, optionally add the prefix before each key
    new = obj.copy() if prefix is None else { '{}_{}'.format(prefix, k): v for k, v in obj.items() }

    # try to find the key holding the subobject or a list of subobjects
    for k, v in new.items():
        # list of subobjects
        if isinstance(v, list):
            del new[k]
            return new, k, v
        # or just one subobject
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            del new[k]
            return new, k, [v]
    return new, None, None

def flatten (data, prefix = None):
    '''
    Flatten the data, optionally with each key prefixed.
    '''
    # iterate all items
    for item in data:
        # split the object
        flat, key, subs = splitObj(item, prefix)

        # just return fully flat objects
        if key is None:
            yield flat
            continue

        # otherwise recursively flatten the subobjects
        for sub in flatten(subs, key):
            sub.update(flat)
            yield sub
```

But as my input has changed as well a bit:

```
input = [{'states': ['USED'], 'niceName': '1-series', 'id': 'BMW_1_Series',
            'years': [{'styles':
                       [{'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'},
                         'name': '128i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 100994560},
                        {'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'},
                          'name': '128i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 100974974},
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 100974975},
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 100994561}
                        ],
                       'states': ['USED'], 'id': 100524709, 'year': 2008},
                      {'styles':
                       [{'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101082656}, 
                        {'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101082655},
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101082663},
                        {'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101082662}
                        ], 
                       'states': ['USED'], 'id': 100503222, 'year': 2009},
                      {'styles': 
                       [{'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101200599},
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101200600}, 
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101200607}, 
                        {'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101200601}
                        ], 
                       'states': ['USED'], 'id': 100529091, 'year': 2010}, 
                      {'styles':
                       [{'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101288165}, 
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101288166}, 
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101288298}, 
                        {'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101288297}
                        ], 
                       'states': ['USED'], 'id': 100531309, 'year': 2011}, 
                      {'styles': 
                       [{'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101381667}, 
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101381668}, 
                        {'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 101381665}, 
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 101381666}
                        ], 
                       'states': ['USED'], 'id': 100534729, 'year': 2012}, 
                      {'styles': 
                       [{'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                        'name': '128i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 200428722},
                        {'trim': '128i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '128i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 200428721}, 
                        {'trim': '135is', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '135is 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 200421701}, 
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 200428724}, 
                        {'trim': '135i', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '135i 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 200428723}, 
                        {'trim': '128i SULEV', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Coupe', 'niceName': 'coupe', 'modelName': '1 Series Coupe'}, 
                         'name': '128i SULEV 2dr Coupe (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 200428726}, 
                        {'trim': '128i SULEV', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '128i SULEV 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl 6M)', 'id': 200428725}, 
                        {'trim': '135is', 'states': ['USED'], 'submodel': {'body': 'Convertible', 'niceName': 'convertible', 'modelName': '1 Series Convertible'}, 
                         'name': '135is 2dr Convertible (3.0L 6cyl Turbo 6M)', 'id': 200428727}
                        ], 
                       'states': ['USED'], 'id': 200421700, 'year': 2013}
                      ], 
          'name': '1 Series', 'make': {'niceName': 'bmw', 'name': 'BMW', 'id': 200000081}
          }]
```

But I receive the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'
```

as it is not handling `'states': ['USED']` i think

What can I do about it?

I moved this problem to [Flatten nested JSON (Dict, List) into List to prepare to write into DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731480/flatten-nested-json-dict-list-into-list-to-prepare-to-write-into-db-python)
Please comment there. Thanks!

Comment: @PSzaf: Do you have an idea on how to handle such a case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the neatest solution, but I think this does what you want it to do:

```
def flatten(something,parent_key=None):

    if parent_key==None:
        prefix = ""
    else:
        prefix = parent_key+"_"

    if type(something) == type({}):
        temp={}
        for key in something:
            temp.update(flatten(something[key],prefix+key))
        return temp

    elif type(something) == type([]):
        temp = {}
        for index in range(len(something)):
            temp.update(flatten(something[index],prefix+str(index)))
        return temp

    else:
        return {parent_key:something}
```

then just run it like:

```
if __name__=='__main__':


input_list = [{"id":"BMW_1_Series",
        "years":[{"id":10052,"year":2008,
                    "styles":[{"id":560,"name":"128i 2",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conve"},"trim":"128i"},
                              {"id":561,"name":"135i ",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conver"},"trim":"135i"}
                              ]
                  },
                 {"id":427,"year":2016,
                  "styles":[{"id":433,"name":"228i ",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Conve", "niceName":"conver"},"trim":"228i SULEV"},
                            {"id":431,"name":"M235i",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Coupe", "niceName":"m235i"},"trim":"M235i"}
                            ]
                  }
                 ]
          }
         #I deleted the other entries, but it is a list
         ]

    a = flatten(input_list)
    print(a)
```

if you can guarantee an id in each list you can use the id in place of the index:

```
temp.update(flatten(something[index],prefix+str(something[index]['id'])))
```

Comment: Thanks PSzaf. That looks awesome so far, although I need a new row for each submodel with all the parent information in it.

Comment: My pleasure!  All the best!

Comment: @BertMaier I'm not sure what you mean by new row for each submodel.  Do you mean a new list element for each model?  If so then you don't need to flatten the JSON all the way, just to a certain point.  I'll give it another shot and take a guess at what you mean

Comment: Hey @PSzaf.
exactely, i meant a new list element.
Thanks

Comment: @BertMaier, great!  took another shot at it, take a look above!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, to both flatten and denormalize arbitrary JSON - including those without a pre-defined schema.  I also wanted to make sure that the one-to-one and one-to-many relationship between all elements in the JSON tree were preserved in the flattened/denormalized version.

So far, this has worked for all use cases I've tried (with files with one JSON record per line, not for multi-line JSON).

https://github.com/bundgus/py_curate_json

Comment: Hey Mark,
looks good, but which file/ class/ function do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it. Closer to your requirements.

```
from pprint import pprint
input = [{"id":"BMW_1_Series",
        "years":[{"id":10052,"year":2008,
                    "styles":[{"id":560,"name":"128i 2",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conve"},"trim":"128i"},
                              {"id":561,"name":"135i ",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conver"},"trim":"135i"}
                              ]
                  },
                 {"id":427,"year":2016,
                  "styles":[{"id":433,"name":"228i ",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Conve", "niceName":"conver"},"trim":"228i SULEV"},
                            {"id":431,"name":"M235i",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Coupe", "niceName":"m235i"},"trim":"M235i"}
                            ]
                  }
                 ]
          }
         #I deleted the other entries, but it is a list
         ]
ds=input[0]["years"][0]
pprint(ds)
def flatten_ds(ds, final_ds={},  prepend_tag=None):
    if type(ds) is dict:
        for k, v in ds.iteritems():
            if not (type(v) is list or type(v) is dict):
                if prepend_tag:
                    k = prepend_tag + '_' + k
                final_ds[k] = v
            else:
                final_ds =  flatten_ds(v, prepend_tag=k, final_ds=final_ds)
        return final_ds

        return final_ds
    if type(ds) is list:
        for d in ds:
            final_ds = flatten_ds(d, prepend_tag=prepend_tag, final_ds=final_ds)
            return final_ds

pprint(flatten_ds(ds))
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy,
that looks the best so far. I still need to figure out that it creates multiple rows (in a list as an output). for every sub-dict/ list that exists

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to flatten your JSON, but you only want to flatten it when you encounter a certain key or keys.  If that's the case you can try this:

Given:

```
from pprint import pprint

input_list = [{"id":"BMW_1_Series",
        "years":[{"id":10052,"year":2008,
                    "styles":[{"id":560,"name":"128i 2",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conve"},"trim":"128i"},
                              {"id":561,"name":"135i ",
                               "submodel":{"body":"Conver","niceName":"conver"},"trim":"135i"}
                              ]
                  },
                 {"id":427,"year":2016,
                  "styles":[{"id":433,"name":"228i ",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Conve", "niceName":"conver"},"trim":"228i SULEV"},
                            {"id":431,"name":"M235i",
                             "submodel":{"body":"Coupe", "niceName":"m235i"},"trim":"M235i"}
                            ]
                  }
                 ]
          }
         #I deleted the other entries, but it is a list
         ]
```

Use the functions:

```
def flatten(something,parent_key=None):
    if parent_key==None:
        prefix = ""
    else:
        prefix = parent_key+"_"

    if type(something) == type({}):
        temp={}
        for key in something:
            temp.update(flatten(something[key],prefix+key))

        return temp

    elif type(something) == type([]):
        temp = {}
        for index in range(len(something)):
            temp.update(flatten(something[index],prefix+str(index)))
            # temp.update(flatten(something[index],prefix+str(something[index]['id'])))

        return temp
    else:
        return {parent_key:something}

def sometimes_flatten(something, flatten_keys):
    if type(something) == type({}):
        temp={}
        for key in something:
            if key in flatten_keys:
                temp.update(flatten(something[key],key))
            else:
                temp.update({key:sometimes_flatten(something[key],flatten_keys)})
        return temp

    elif type(something) == type([]):
        return [sometimes_flatten(x,flatten_keys) for x in something]

    else:
        return something
```

then call them here:

```
if __name__=='__main__':

    flatten_keys = ['years']

    a = sometimes_flatten(input_list,flatten_keys)

    pprint(a)
```

but you can put any of the keys into the `flatten_keys` variable to change how it behaves and how much flattening it will do

Comment: thanks for your input. For the input provided, i would need 4 entries in the output list as there where 4 different styles in the JSON File. How would you go about that?

Comment: Check out the preliminary solution i posted under UPDATE. Do you have an idea on how to solve it?